# Auto spawn rabbit mq listener

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm working on an application where-in I have a listener on a rabbit mq queue. Depending on the kind of message, the listener goes ahead and performs a task. My problem is I need a way to spawn a new listener if a single listener isn't able to cope up with the queue. As far as I can tell, I can use the rabbitmq json api to find the len of the queue and take actions based on that. So, I write a script that checks using curl the queue length and spawns a new listener process. Am I on the right path here? Is there a better way to achieve this? I'm looking for a solution that kinda scales with load to a certain limit atleast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the RabbitMQ API to see the length of the queue is one way, and it would definitely work.

You should try to predict when the load is spiking so that you slowly can increase the number of consumers if needed, so that you don't see a sudden spike of instances spawning. Having many instances spawning simultaneously could cause unnecessary load on your system.

Comment: For our system, I've been struggling to define "load". Queue length is the only thing I could come up with and so I'm thinking of ways to check the number of instances and probably shut down unused instances, and work with that for now. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If you use the RabbitMQ API you can also see things like ```rate``` under ```message_stats```. As an example you could check and see if the incoming rate is high. If it is above lets say 5 messages per second and you can only hand 4, you know you will need more consumers even before the queue gets high.

Comment: You can also compare how many messages are getting acknowledged per second by the consumer as opposed to how many messages are being sent to RabbitMQ.

Comment: Thanks eandersson. These are great suggestions

Comment: BTW, just add to the answer that `queue.declare` idempotent AMQP method returns messages number in queue, so it may be used somehow if you don't want to play with API calls and curl.

Comment: @zaq178miami: It does indeed. I would use that if monitoring is handled by the consumer itself, or at least if part of it is handling it, as you already have a connection. Less overhead, and not having to install the management module is always an added bonus!